# Unable to install tomcat in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java

I first installed tomcat 8 manually but failed to start after that i installed tomcat 7 using apt-get but was unable to start the server...i have changed many files HOME and catilina variables but no fruit....can some one help or is there any alternative for tomcat

Comment: What is the exact problem? What is the error message you get while starting the server?

Comment: Ask ... askubuntu.com; or maybe superuser.com

Comment: When you state that you have CHANGED various files/variables, it is best to include exactly what you change so we can see your errors/misconfigurations.

Comment: i checked tomcat 8 was running on terminal but i was unable to access the homepage on browser

Comment: Tomcat 8 installs and works on Ubuntu 15.04 like a charm and it is in fact difficult to make it go wrong. This questions provides no detail about how the manual installation was performed, what and how was configured and which dependencies were present on the system (e.g. Java). The question further does not clarify if Tomcat 7 remained on the system and when it failed to run then what was the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is A guide from Digital Ocean

[Install Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-14-04)

If you still having issues you need to post your exactly what you changed and so forth so we can have a grasp on what you did to make it not a quick install.

Comment: using this i installed but unable was to access tomcat homepage

Comment: Does tomcat startup? Whats your error? Who is hosting the server? is it local? There more to just getting the tomcat server to run for it to serve up a page. You need to post more information (like the error message)  if you expect to get the right answer.

Comment: initctl: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused
this is the error i m getting

Comment: Are you on a dedicated machine, your localhost, a docker container, or a vps? Also what specific ubuntu version?

Comment: localhost ,gnome-ubuntu 15.04

Comment: can you please tell me an alternate for tomcat

Comment: If you are trying to run a JAVA application you have a few choices - mainly Tomcat, if you choose to go with an OSGI compliant application you could build using AETOS containers but realistically you should probably use tomcat. As for the error you are getting you mentioned you changed variables - what variables did you change?

Comment: Have you tried running the tomcat server directly instead of using upstart/initd/systemd? ( /path/to/tomcat/bin/startup.sh )

Comment: how to start directly

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy and extract the tomcat tar file from to any directory structure , you prefer. (Say /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21). You can then add following to /etc/profile.

```
CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21 
 export CATALINA_HOME
```

Comment: Error : Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused